# Restriction on length of query parameters

Tags: java, rest, get

Do we still have any limitation on length of query params on GET operations. Earlier I think i used t be 255, which seems increased but i don't know whats that increased limitation.

The problem i am facing is 
I tried GET For endpoint like http://localhost:8080/data/ids=<**5000** comma seaprated ids>, it fails

but same request with 500 ids like http://localhost:8080/data/ids=<**500** comma seaprated ids> succeeds and so i doubt its length issue.

Please advise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends more on the configuration of the web server your application is running on.

For Apache Tomcat you can configure this value using following parameter in server.xml configuration file:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ... />
```

For Jetty it should be:

```
<Set name="requestHeaderSize">65535</Set>
```